# Opacity on first and last element of slider which has ".active" classes using javascript or css

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, owl-carousel

I have owl carousel slider with 5 items. And my problem is that i need first and last element of my slider to be always with opacity. Slider has like 15 elements which 9 cloned, 5 have `.active` class and one with cloned and `.active`.

I tryied make it using javascript where i found all ".active" classes in slider, but i don't exactly know what i should do with object which was found.

There is code which found all ".active" classes

```
var owlCarouselActive = document.getElementById("slider-tour").getElementsByClassName("owl-item active");
```

I need in order to this `.active` first and last have :before with my background style when i click on button prev or next.

[image: i added link which image where you can see what i want]

[image: There is layout]

Comment: does owl carousel not use jquery? if so you can just get the first and last active elements by `$('.owl-stage .active').first()` and `$('.owl-stage .active').last()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with javascript

```
 var owlCarouselActive = document.getElementsByClassName("owl-item active");
 var first = owlCarouselActive[0]; //get first item
 var last = owlCarouselActive[owlCarouselActive.length - 1]; //get last item

 first.style.opacity = 0.8;
 last.style.opacity = 0.8;
```

Comment: will it not really show us how "undefined"? because when i check this out as console.log(first + " ," + last); it showed me how "undefined" both

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at home but try something like this:

```
function setOpacity() {
    var elements = $('.active');
    let count = 0;

    $(elements).each(function(k,v) {
       if (count == 0 || count == elements.length - 1) {
          $(v).css('opacity', '0.8');
       }
       count++;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   setOpacity();
});
```

Run that function everytime you want it to update.
E.G on a button click.

Comment: `:first` is only for use with pages: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first.  If you mean `:first-child` then that won't get the first active class - it will get the first child that also has a class active

Comment: No, it isn't work. And it seem like :last does't exist? May be you mean first-child and last-child? If you want use them, it won't work because first-child take first element in block(this should be first), and last-child do same with last

Comment: @Aaron NoHuanKnows, yeah, this one is works but not well. When i click on button this add opacity in active, but if i click another one it add to prev div one more time and more)) I added to ready(function) works setOpacity(); when i click on button

Answer (score 0):

You can use **owlCarouselActive [0]** to access the first element and **owlCarouselActive [owlCarouselActive.length-1]** to access the last element. Generally you can access i-th element by **owlCarouselActive [i]**.